# Regex regular expression notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have written a simple expression which should find word starting with 3 tabs and follows the given rules. The problem is that it is finding things that contain 5 tabs as well. How can I get only things with 3 tabs?

```
\t{3}\"id":\s\".+"\,
```

Comment: Then use a lookbehind, `(?<!\t)\t{3}"id":\s*".*?",`

Comment: Please show us example. Wiktor's method is awesome.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I have bunch of ids numbers which I would like to change to numbers.
    "Id": "3L2kVk16n", into "id": "1001"
   "Id": "3L2kVk16p", into "id": "1002"
   "Id": "3L2kVk16r", into "id": "1003"
is there any way to do it in notepad++ without changing each manually?

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? Please edit it so that we could understand what you really need and how to help you.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I have added directly in question it starts with words "My second question".  Soryy I am new I appreciate any help

Comment: Sorry, anything which starts with "My second question ..." better goes into a second question post. Try to make this single question answerable. You can add additional details, but avoid the impression of asking more than one question in one post.

Comment: Does `(?<!\t)\t{3}"id":\s*".*?",` answer **this** current question?

Comment: Hi Viktor, yes, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<!\t)\t{3}"id":\s*".*?",
```

*Details*:

- `(?<!\t)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a TAB char immediately on the left
- `\t{3}` - three TAB chars
- `"id":` - a literal string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `",` - a `",` substring.